# Enumitem, Listings, Tabbing to a Certain Point

Tags: listings, enumitem

I was wondering whether it was possible to align a `lstlisting` environment to a certain point within an `enumerate` . The purpose of my doing this is to fit as much code sample on the page as possible, while maintaining a two-column environment.

In the following code sample:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem, listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First enumerate level
\begin{lstlisting}[frame = single]
First code sample
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Text that is stationary
\begin{lstlisting}[frame = single, breaklines = true, breakindent = 0pt]
Code sample that has the same alignment as the First code sample
\end{lstlisting}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The code sample produces:

[image: Code Sample Alignment]

How do I move the second code sample to the left, so that its alignment is the same as the first code sample?

Note that I have tried using `\end{enumerate}` and `\begin{enumerate}[resume]`. However, this only seems to suspend the level of enumeration 1 level.

Also, I have tried exiting the `enumerate` environment altogether by doing `\end{enumerate}` before the `lstlisting` environment. However, sometimes I have items following the `lstlisting` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at section 4.10 of the `listings` manual you can find a few keys that manipulate the horziontal alignment of a `lstlisting` environment.

- The option `resetmargins` reset the margins of environment like `itemize` and `enumerate`.
- The option `xleftmargin=\leftmargin` pushes the listing back to the first level.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem, listings, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First enumerate level
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame = single]
First code sample
    \end{lstlisting}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item Second level
            \begin{enumerate}
            \item Third level
            \begin{lstlisting}[
                resetmargins=true,
                xleftmargin=\leftmargin,
                frame = single, breaklines = true, breakindent = 0pt]
Code sample that has the same alignment as the First code sample
            \end{lstlisting}
            \item Last point in inner level
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Last point in second level
    \end{enumerate}
    \item And again first level
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: Output of code]

Comment: Yes, resume works at one level. But if I have nested enumerate levels, the resume will only go back 1 level. For example, if I am at the 4th level of enumerate, and I \end{enumerate} and \begin{enumerate}[resume], the block that is between those two commands is at the 3rd level. (So, level 4 with resume -> level 3, and lvl. 3 with res. -> lvl. 2, and lvl. 2 with res. -> lvl. 1) <=> (4 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 1). I was wondering whether there was a way to move the block to the 1st level.

Comment: @jrand I've updated my answer. If this is typographically a good idea is another topic, though.

Comment: Yes, the answer has to do with xleftmargin and careful use (linear combination) of \framesep, \leftmargini, and some other margin values.

Comment: For the purpose of exactness, the left margins of the code samples will be perfectly aligned if \leftmargin is replaced with \leftmargini .